# bash: read text file, get HTTP headers, save results

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using Terminal in OS X 10.8
The challenge is to read text file (where each line is an url), get HTTP headers, save results to other text file

Tried this:

```
for line in cat ~/Desktop/a.txt; do curl -I line > ~/Desktop/b.txt;  done
```

plus multiple loop examples like

```
(while read l; do echo $l; done) < ~/Desktop/a.txt
```

or

```
cat ~/Desktop/a.txt | while read CMD; do
echo $CMD
done
```

It seems to me that I cannot create simple loop.
Please, advise.
Best,

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
for i in $(cat test); do curl -I $i >> test2; done
```

This reads everything in the file `test` and appends the curl output to the file `test2`.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. Unfortunately, it does not work :(

Comment: sorry, just found out that input file was empty (because of my recent experiments probably). the error is nodename nor servname provided, or not known